# Create dynamic css class ex .font-size { font-size: size}

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create dynamic css font classes such as in the title where `size` in `.font-size` become the parameter used as `size` :

```
.font-size { 
     font-size: size px;
}
```

and you could add

```
<p class="font-14">
```

which would call

```
.font-14 {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: As far as i know answer is No. CSS is not a programming language. Your example is called 'Atomic CSS'. And they had a some tools that may help. http://acss.io/

Comment: But css has some dynamic properties. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr-notation; They are not realized yet, not all. http://www.dreamdealer.nl/articles/using_the_data_attribute_as_content_in_css.html

Comment: Though you can select all classes beginning by `font-`: `[class^="font-"]`, you can't parse or make use of the characters following it. Also [CSS (not so) variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) won't help you AFAIK. +1 for No you can't

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dynamicaly generate the CSS font declarations with the corresponding classes, you should look into [CSS Preprocessors](http://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/) like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Here is an example with SCSS :

```
@for $i from 14 through 30 {
  .font-#{$i} {
    font-size: $i + px; 
  }
}
```

This will output :

```
.font-14 { font-size: 14px; }
.font-15 { font-size: 15px; }
.font-16 { font-size: 16px; }
...
.font-30 { font-size: 30px; }
```

Comment: @0x860111 what isn't dynamic?

Comment: Questions title is 'Create dynamic css class ex .font-size { font-size: size}'. First half of your answer is about how to achieve something like that. But it is not a dynamic solution.

Comment: They are not dynamic too, honestly. Anyway, you will give browser a compiled css.

Comment: @0x860111 true but it will avoid the hassle of typing each declaration and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: If it's static and covers 100% of the cases, no need for dynamic :) @0x860111 `calc(100% - 20px)` is both dynamic (unknown value till the browser has to evaluate it and it can change if viewport or a parent is resized) and "compiled" (from a preprocessor) or vanilla CSS

Comment: Maybe no need for dynamic. But question is not about 'how achieve something like that', question is about possibility of doing that by css. It is not the same. And atomicCSS can cover 100% of cases. How about `margin-12312` or `color-32452` or something like that? If should be a `param` and dymanicly generated by browser, as a ts wants.